# Glassfish doesn't deploy all modules of the war

Tags: soap, glassfish-4, netbeans-8

I am using netbeans 8 and glassfish 4.1. I am trying to deploy a war on glassfish. But all the modules of the war do not get deployed. There are a total of 4 modules out of which only 2 modules get deployed. The same war deploys correctly on the glassfish on the local machine but gives problems while deploying on the development server.

Comment: Can you give some more details of what's going wrong? What are these modules? Are there any error messages in the `server.log`? What have you done so far to diagnose the problem?

Comment: 4 modules contain soap services. I compared the logs of my local machine and that of the server and did not find anything different apart from the statements that mention which module is deployed. eg `EJB Endpoint deployed App
  listening at address at http://mumch-29684:8080/AppService/AppService`. Also I undeployed the application, deleted all the files from the server and redeployed the application. But still facing the same issue. What else would you suggest?

Comment: Are you deploying in the same way on each, or using Netbeans to deploy locally?